# Extract values from one list of dicts into another

Tags: python, list, dictionary

How can I copy specific items from one list to another? My original is:

```
[
    {
        "values" : {
            "val1"    : 334,
            "val2"   : 994,
            "val3"  : 33,
            "val4" : 345,
        },
        "filename": "image1.jpg",
    },
    {
        "values" : {
            "val1"    : 567,
            "val2"   : 777,
            "val3"  : 787,
            "val4" : 678,
        },
        "filename": "image2.jpg",
    },
]
```

And I want my new array to look like this:

```
[
    {
        "index" : 0,
        "filename": "image1.jpg",
        "val1: 334,
        "val3: 33,
    },
    {
        "index" : 1,
        "filename": "image2.jpg",
        "val1: 567,
        "val3: 787,
    },
]
```

I have tried this but it is not working:

```
for (i, x) in original:
        new.extend([{
            "index" : i,
            "filename" : x.filename,
            "val1" : x.val1,
            "val2" : x.val2,
        }])
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this maybe:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
original=[
    {
        "values" : {
            "val1"    : 334,
            "val2"   : 994,
            "val3"  : 33,
            "val4" : 345,
        },
        "filename": "image1.jpg",
    },
    {
        "values" : {
            "val1"    : 567,
            "val2"   : 777,
            "val3"  : 787,
            "val4" : 678,
        },
        "filename": "image2.jpg",
    },
]
new=[]
for (i, x) in enumerate(original):
        new.append({
            "index" : i,
            "filename" : x["filename"],
            "val1" : x["values"]["val1"],
            "val2" : x["values"]["val2"],
        })
print(new)
```

Comment: Nearly the same solution here, but I used `extend` instead of `append`

Comment: Yeah I was going to suggest appending, not extending.

Comment: I did a small fix. If you use `append` you don't have to wrap the appended dictionary in a list.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
def f(x):
    y = []
    for i, j in enumerate(x):
        z = {}
        z["index"] = i
        z["filename"] = j["filename"]
        for k, m in enumerate(j["values"]):
            z[f"val{k + 1}"] = j["values"][m]
        y.append(z)
    return y


x = [
    {
        "values" : {
            "val1"    : 334,
            "val2"   : 994,
            "val3"  : 33,
            "val4" : 345,
        },
        "filename": "image1.jpg",
    },
    {
        "values" : {
            "val1"    : 567,
            "val2"   : 777,
            "val3"  : 787,
            "val4" : 678,
        },
        "filename": "image2.jpg",
    },
]

print(f(x))
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, assuming your `original` is the list at the top, you will need to enumerate it instead of iterating like it's a dictionary. Next, if you look at your input, the values are actually at the second layer.

Your code should look like:

```
transformed_dicts = []
for i, orig_dict in enumerate(original):
    transformed = {
        'index': i,
        'filename': orig_dict['filename'],
        'val1': orig_dict['values']['val1'],
        'val3': orig_dict['values']['val3'],
    }
    transformed_dicts.append(transformed)
```

You can "refactor" this to use list comprehension, but I think this way is more readable.

Answer (score 1):

I pretty much came up with the same answer as Mayhem, but note that `val3` is asked for in the question even though the sample code gets `val2`. Not a dealbreaker I'm sure. I used (maybe abused) a list comprehension instead of the loop as well.

```
result = [{'index': i, 
  'filename': val['filename'],
  'val1': val['values']['val1'],
  'val3': val['values']['val3']
  } for i, val in enumerate(original)]

print(result)
```

Output is:

> [{'index': 0, 'filename': 'image1.jpg', 'val1': 334, 'val3': 33},
>   {'index': 1, 'filename': 'image2.jpg', 'val1': 567, 'val3': 787}]

Answer (score 0):

I would say you are going wrong in using 2 variables to iterate over a list.

The solution I propose would be as follows:

```py
records = []
index = 0
for i in original:
    record = {'index': index,
              'filename': i['filename'],
              'val1': i['values']['val1'],
              'val3': i['values']['val3']}
    index += 1
    records.append(record)
```